# Why am I unable to connect to my Anvil-launched ETH node using 'cast' command?

Tags: anvil

I launched an ETH node using Anvil, but I cannot connect to it with `cast`. However, I can successfully call the RPC API using Postman.

```
E:\web3project\hello_foundry>anvil

?[32m
                             _   _
                            (_) | |
      __ _   _ __   __   __  _  | |
     / _` | | '_ \  \ \ / / | | | |
    | (_| | | | | |  \ V /  | | | |
     \__,_| |_| |_|   \_/   |_| |_|
?[0m
    0.1.0 (58a2729 2023-05-16T10:55:17.415866700Z)
    ?[32mhttps://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry?[0m

Available Accounts
==================

(0) "0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266" (10000 ETH)
(1) "0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8" (10000 ETH)
(2) "0x3C44CdDdB6a900fa2b585dd299e03d12FA4293BC" (10000 ETH)
(3) "0x90F79bf6EB2c4f870365E785982E1f101E93b906" (10000 ETH)
(4) "0x15d34AAf54267DB7D7c367839AAf71A00a2C6A65" (10000 ETH)
(5) "0x9965507D1a55bcC2695C58ba16FB37d819B0A4dc" (10000 ETH)
(6) "0x976EA74026E726554dB657fA54763abd0C3a0aa9" (10000 ETH)
(7) "0x14dC79964da2C08b23698B3D3cc7Ca32193d9955" (10000 ETH)
(8) "0x23618e81E3f5cdF7f54C3d65f7FBc0aBf5B21E8f" (10000 ETH)
(9) "0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720" (10000 ETH)

Private Keys
==================

(0) 0xac0974bec39a17e36ba4a6b4d238ff944bacb478cbed5efcae784d7bf4f2ff80
(1) 0x59c6995e998f97a5a0044966f0945389dc9e86dae88c7a8412f4603b6b78690d
(2) 0x5de4111afa1a4b94908f83103eb1f1706367c2e68ca870fc3fb9a804cdab365a
(3) 0x7c852118294e51e653712a81e05800f419141751be58f605c371e15141b007a6
(4) 0x47e179ec197488593b187f80a00eb0da91f1b9d0b13f8733639f19c30a34926a
(5) 0x8b3a350cf5c34c9194ca85829a2df0ec3153be0318b5e2d3348e872092edffba
(6) 0x92db14e403b83dfe3df233f83dfa3a0d7096f21ca9b0d6d6b8d88b2b4ec1564e
(7) 0x4bbbf85ce3377467afe5d46f804f221813b2bb87f24d81f60f1fcdbf7cbf4356
(8) 0xdbda1821b80551c9d65939329250298aa3472ba22feea921c0cf5d620ea67b97
(9) 0x2a871d0798f97d79848a013d4936a73bf4cc922c825d33c1cf7073dff6d409c6

Wallet
==================
Mnemonic:          test test test test test test test test test test test junk
Derivation path:   m/44'/60'/0'/0/


Base Fee
==================
?[32m
1000000000?[0m

Gas Limit
==================
?[32m
30000000?[0m

Genesis Timestamp
==================
?[32m
1684753790?[0m

Listening on 127.0.0.1:8545

`

`E:\web3project\hello_foundry>cast gas-price --rpc-url http://127.0.0.1:8545
Error:
Deserialization Error: EOF while parsing a value at line 1 column 0. Response:
```

[image]

[image]